# ActionExtension Icon

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change default Action Extension icon but unfortunately no result. Some topics I could find look outdated already.

What I already did:

1. Added `Assets.xcassets` folder to the `ActionExtension` folder.
2. Added `App Icon` type image named `AppIcon` and provided all image sizes with transparent background.
3. In Build Settings of the Action Extension for `Primary App Icon Set Name` field set `AppIcon` as a value.

So I see the target image was changed but still in the iPhone gallery where I try to run the action extension it shows default main app icon.

Would be thankful for any suggestions.
Thanks